# $(...).autocomplete is not a function Error occurs when the page is load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In my web application, I have added a text box and I wanted to search for data and show it while typing on it.

So I followed this video and added the same to my project. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5v8a575QX0

But when the page loads, I got this error in the console.```$(...).autocomplete is not a function``

I have to google it and found some jquery libraries are missing so I downloaded the files and included them in my project and then mapped them to it from the view.

But still, the error is the same.

```
<link href="~/Addons/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<link href="~/Addons/autocomplete/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Addons/autocomplete/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Addons/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type the Item Name or Number Here" class="form-control" id="itemSerachBox" />
  </div>

$(function () {
  $("#itemSerachBox").autocomplete({
    sourse: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchItems","Ajax")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          search: $("itemSerachBox").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
          response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
              label: item.ItemName_Number,
              value: item.ID
            };
          }));
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          toastr.error("Invalid Item");
        }
      });

    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Should `$("#itemSerachBox")` be `$("#itemSearchBox")`?

Comment: `.autocomplete()` isn't a built-in jQuery function. You're probably missing including a plugin. The video appears to be using jQuery UI ~ https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: The problem with this question is the incomplete code. We can't tell what JavaScript you've loaded, when, or in what order. All these things are important. Create an [mcve] and post that.

Comment: Maybe you haven't imported the cdn of jquery auto complete or the library was imported first before the jquery itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your support.

I finally found that the codings and the reference are correct, but the javascripts are in conflict with other scripts.

That's why I got this error and then I managed to move some script to the Layout and then this worked.

Once again thank you for the support

Answer (score -1):

Since autocomplete is not a built-in function, you have to include the desired plugins in your project. Since the code you provided does not show the scripts tag you have included I will provide you with the necessary things needed:

1. Make sure that you have included the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts in your project and that they are loaded before the code that uses the autocomplete function.
2. Place your autocomplete code inside document.ready to ensure that the code is executed after the document has finished loading.

```
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#itemSerachBox").autocomplete({
         // your code
    });
```

Comment: What JavaScript files are loaded, when, and in what order are all important, but your sample code misses all of that. It would be very easy to get all that wrong, use what you have provided and still find that things don't work.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Sorry for the incomplete code. I forgot to paste the scripts. Now I have updated the question.

Comment: @PrenaKakria I have edited my question with the script. Sory for the inconvenience. I have changed my code according to yours, But still ``autocomplete`` function not triggers when typing.

Comment: You are not including the right script tags in your project. Please add these three scripts in your head tag:
     <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">

      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>